# absolut convergence of the Laplace transform of a intensity measure

Tags: measure-theory, laplace-transform, absolute-convergence, point-processes

Let $\xi$ be a point process and $\mu$ its intensity measure, i.e.
$\mu(\cdot)=\mathbb{E}[\xi(\cdot)]$. The Laplace transform of $\mu$:

$\mathcal{L}\mu(z)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zx}\mu(dx)$

converges for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ absolutely.

**Does anyone know which (absolut) convergence criterion to use here?**

**And what does the Laplace transformation do with the intensity measure here? Is there any way to visualize this?**